# RoR - Time.strptime issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the method in question.

```
def published_at_setter
    self.published_at = Time.strptime("#{@date} #{@time}", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
    puts " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #{@date} #{@time} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #{self.published_at}"
end
```

With @date = "09/11/2012" and @time "01:45 AM" I get this in the webbrick console. WFT?

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 09/11/2012 01:45 AM ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2012-09-11 06:45:00 UTC
```

When in rails console I get the expected results. "2012-09-11 01:45:00 -0500"

Comment: have you tried `strftime` instead? here is the doc http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime : it returns a string, `strptime` seems to return a Date object ( http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class )

Comment: The task I have is to take a string such as "09/11/2012 01:45 AM" and convert it into a DateTime thus why you see the interpolated string with Time.strptime. I not sure how strftime would work if I had a string to start with.

Comment: have you tried time.localtime instead of just time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Time.strptime`, you should use `Time.zone.parse`.

```
def published_at_setter
    self.published_at = Time.zone.parse("#{@date} #{@time}")
    puts " ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #{@date} #{@time} ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #{self.published_at}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, I had thoughts that it was a time zone issue but was not sure what to do.